# R: Application of group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm just getting started using dplyr and I have the following two problems, which should be easy to solve with `group_by`, but I don't get it.
I have data that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind("year" = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012),
                     "institution" = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
                     "branch.num" = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2)))

data
#  year institution branch.num
#1 2010           a          1
#2 2010           a          2
#3 2010           b          1
#4 2011           a          1
#5 2012           a          1
#6 2012           a          2
#7 2012           b          1
#8 2012           b          2
```

The data is structured hierarchical: An institution at the highest level can a several branches, which are numbered starting at 1.

Problem 1: I want to select the rows containing only branches, for which exists a value in every year, that is in the example data only Branch 1 of Institution a, so the selection should be lines 1, 4 and 5.

Pronlem 2: I want to know the average number of branches a institution has over all years. That is in the example for Institution a (2+1+2)/3 = 1.67 and for institution b (1+0+2)/3 = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

Problem #1:

```
library(dplyr)
nYears <- n_distinct(data$year)
data %>% group_by(institution, branch.num) %>% filter(n_distinct(year) == nYears)
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: institution, branch.num [1]

    year institution branch.num
  (fctr)      (fctr)     (fctr)
1   2010           a          1
2   2011           a          1
3   2012           a          1
```

Problem #2:

```
data %>% group_by(institution, year) %>% summarise(nBranches = n_distinct(branch.num)) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(institution) %>% summarise(meanBranches = sum(nBranches)/nYears)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  institution meanBranches
       (fctr)        (dbl)
1           a     1.666667
2           b     1.000000
```